html-to-image: exports html to SVG image without font (JavaScript)
I'm trying to export div from html file to SVG image.
I'm using imported fonts.

It's working except the fonts.
Maybe there is some specific way to import font in html-to-image?
The error text:

Access to fetch at 'file:///...Raleway-Medium.ttf' from origin 'null'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app,
chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
ET file:///.../Raleway-Medium.ttf net::ERR_FAILED

My code:
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: Raleway;
            src: url("Raleway-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        #my-node {
            font-family: "Raleway";
        }

        .myDiv {
            padding: 2px;
            border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
        }

        .myText {
            font-size: 15px;
            letter-spacing: 0.02em;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my-node">
    <div class="myDiv" style="top: 100px; left: 100px;">
        <span class="myText">Here is some text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html-to-image/1.11.11/html-to-image.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function filter(node) {
        return (node.tagName !== 'i');
    }
    htmlToImage.toSvg(document.getElementById('my-node'), {filter: filter})
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            let svg = decodeURIComponent(dataUrl.split(',')[1])
            console.log(svg);
        });
</script>
</body>


You need to convert you external font reference to a data URL to make the svg self contained. See this post "Converting and rendering web fonts to base64 - keep original look"

@herrstrietzel it works with local server
